# brew install nginx fails to link

Tags: homebrew

I am attempting to install nginx using the brew package manager, but it fails to link. How can I fix this?

```
roc-web5537:Downloads cmuench$ brew install nginx
Warning: Your Xcode (4.3.3) is outdated
Please install Xcode 4.5.
==> Installing nginx dependency: pcre
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-8.31.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pcre-8.31.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.31 --enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties --enable-pcregrep-libz --enable-pcregrep-libbz2
==> make test
==> make install
Warning: Could not link pcre. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link pcre'
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.31: 130 files, 3.2M, built in 18 seconds
==> Installing nginx
==> Downloading http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/nginx-1.2.4.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file conf/nginx.conf
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.4 --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-ipv6 --with-cc-opt=-I/usr/local/include --with-ld-opt=-L/usr/local/lib --conf-path=/usr/loca
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
In the interest of allowing you to run `nginx` without `sudo`, the default
port is set to localhost:8080.

If you want to host pages on your local machine to the public, you should
change that to localhost:80, and run `sudo nginx`. You'll need to turn off
any other web servers running port 80, of course.

You can start nginx automatically on login running as your user with:
  mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
  cp /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.4/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
  launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist

Though note that if running as your user, the launch agent will fail if you
try to use a port below 1024 (such as http's default of 80.)
Warning: Could not link nginx. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link nginx'
Warning: /usr/local/sbin is not in your PATH
You can amend this by altering your ~/.bashrc file
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.4: 9 files, 952K, built in 9 seconds
```

Answer (score 19):

I had this issue a few days ago with installation of Yeoman. It seems that some of the folders in /usr/local might not be owned by you and that can cause issues. In my case I had a couple of folders in /usr/local/ like that.

Go to /usr/local

```
cd /usr/local
```

Check who owns the folders

```
ls -l
```

Do the following for folders not owned by you (replacing sub-foldername with sub folders name obviously):

```
sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/<sub-foldername>
```

and then call

```
brew link pcre
```

It should link successfully.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This can sometimes happen if there area already files (or symlinks) with the same name. To force a link, you can use `brew link -f pcre`. If you want to see whether there are any files preventing the link, you can use `brew link --dry-run pcre`.

If there are no files listed by `brew link --dry-run pcre`, then it is likely that jwwishart's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove manually and reinstall pcre and openssl then nginx will work:

```
brew remove pcre
brew remove openssl
brew install pcre
brew install openssl
nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Was getting

erma4inapower@MacBook-Pro-Dmitrij  ~  brew services start php
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/erma4inapower/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist

Ended up:

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/erma4inapower/Library/LaunchAgents/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was causing problems while other services using brew.

how to fix run

`brew doctor`

remove all files which are causing the issue. might have to do

`rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"`
`brew tap homebrew/core`

if warning comes up

make sure you are in master branch by

`git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core)`

checkout Important is the brew doctor command which help me fix the issue.