# Error: You must `brew link pcre' before nginx can be installed

Tags: ruby, macos, nginx, passenger, homebrew

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626038/brew-install-nginx-fails-to-link) post. And it didn't seem to solve my issue. Here's what I get when I try to run `brew install nginx --with-passenger`

> Error: You must `brew link pcre' before nginx can be installed

So I then tried `cd /usr/local`, followed by `ls -l`. All of the files are mine. So I don't see the need to call `sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/<sub-foldername>` I've then tried doing `brew link pcre` and yet I get another error. `Error: Could not symlink bin/pcregrep` I'm not really sure what to do now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it working by forcing it with. `brew link --overwrite pcre` This would force the link and overwrite all conflicting files.